# My hard disk with Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop installed does not boot when I restart my PC

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm in a bit of a mess here, I recently formatted my hard drive and installed Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop on it. After the installation I restarted my PC but it never boots up the installed Ubuntu 23.04 and returns

```
Boot Device not found 
Please install an Operating System on your Hard disk. 
Hard Disk - (3F0)
```

I'm using a HP Elitebook 2560P with 2nd Gen Intel i5 chipset and 8GB of RAM, and also a 160gb hard disk drive.
When I plug the hard disk to a reader and plug to another PC it also does not read.

Comment: Guess something went wrong during install (Error during install). On older computer sometimes an empty bios-battery causes problems.

Comment: but I can access my BIOS menu

Comment: But accessing the bios has nothing to do with an empty bios battery.

Comment: Are there other solutions to this?

Comment: Check boot mode in UEFI/BIOS settings. Install based on your choice in boot menu. But default boot is a UEFI setting for either UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. Many posts of HP users with issues. Most eventually get it to work, although some just go back to the old (now very old) BIOS boot mode. You should still keep gpt unless also booting Windows as with BIOS mode, it requires the old MBR(msdos) partitioning. With gpt and BIOS you need a 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag.

Comment: If the bios battery is empty it will switch to bios defaults on next power loss. Maybe you installed in UEFI mode and after power unplug it went to CSM/Legacy (or vice versa) and now it does not boot anymore. Make sure the Bios battery is not empty. Replace it if needed.